# I'm trying to use a select, and I'm using the material-ui example

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I'm trying to use a select, and I'm using the material-ui example
When I use the change() I don't get the value. Any suggestions?

```
<TextField
  select
  name={load.loadDetail.loadType}
  variant="outlined"
  label="Load Type"
  value={load.loadDetail.loadType}
  margin="normal"
  fullWidth
  onChange={handleChange}
>
  <MenuItem>
    <em>Refrigerated</em>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>
    <em>Dry Product</em>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>
    <em>Power Only</em>
  </MenuItem>  
</TextField>
```

Comment: You need to use `Select` instead of `TextField`, if you are trying to follow the example.
https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/#simple-select

Comment: Thank you
I did it, but Select doesn't work with Formik, can you help me with that Formik

Comment: Can you please share a Minimal, complete and verifiable example for your problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The SelectField component in Material UI v1 is currently work in progress. You can see the current progress

```
 import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';

 <Select
        value={this.state.age}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        inputProps={{
          name: 'age',
          id: 'age-simple',
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem value="">
          <em>None</em>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to use either `TextField` or `Select`(as suggested above), the issue with your code is that your `MenuItem` component has no `value` property. 
e.g.

```
<MenuItem key="refrigerated" value="Refrigerated">
 <em>Refrigerated</em>
</MenuItem>
```